# How to dump data into file as json one dictionary at a time in python?

Tags: python, json

At the moment my web crawler is gathering all the data and placing them all into a dictionary, as such:

```
def save_data_to_json(data, json_file_name):
    print 'Saving data into json file...'
    with open(json_file_name, 'a') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile, sort_keys = True, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)

def gather_data(page_url, soup, all_data):
    #return if this page doesn't contain data
    if (soup.find('h4') == None) or (soup.find('span') == None):
        return
    company_name = soup.h4.span.text
    table_body = soup.tbody
    table_rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
    company_data = {}

    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [str(i.text) for i in td]
        if len(row) != 2:
            continue
        company_data[row[0]] = row[1]
        all_data[str(company_name)] = company_data
    #I want to save data here, but saving now instead of later messed up json formatting
    #save_data_to_json(all_data, json_file_name)
```

When doing this way, I must read all the data from every link and dump them into this data dictionary. Is there a way to write each data set for each page into a json formatted file a dictionary set at a time to conserve memory? Attempts have made the json format all messed up because of the extra curly brackets. I only want to output one json file all together.

Comment: You can't put multiple JSONs into a single file, because when you read it back there's no way to tell where one ends and the next one begins.

Comment: So how does production level code create json files when there are a million data sets? They haven't have can't that all stored in ram until they are done searching all the links can they? How do they tackle this?

Comment: Applications that deal with large data sets usually use databases.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [jsonlines](http://jsonlines.org/)
it's a variation on json which is more suitable for "streaming" read or writes.
basically, each line should be a valid json document.

the basic python json library is usually enough (you read a line of text, and the parse this specific line), or you can use helper libraries such as: https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Barmar you have to make your distinct arrangement when you put your JSON content to the file. like passing some special text recognition from which you can find where your JSON ends

Answer (score 0):

First of all, If you'd like to save some memory than use bulks - limit the amount of entities each bulk contains and when it reaches this limit save it to Json (I'll show example).

Next, you can save multiple dictionaries into a single Json, just go to a different line for each dictionary.

```
def gather_data(page_url, soup, all_data, file_path):
    #return if this page doesn't contain data
    max_per_bulk_ = 10000
    if (soup.find('h4') == None) or (soup.find('span') == None):
        return
    company_name = soup.h4.span.text
    table_body = soup.tbody
    table_rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
    company_data = {}
    f = open(file_path, 'a')
    bulk_ = []
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [str(i.text) for i in td]
        if len(row) != 2:
            continue
        company_data[row[0]] = row[1]
        all_data[str(company_name)] = company_data
        if len(bulk_) > max_per_bulk_:
            with open(file_path, 'a') as f:
                for entity in bulk_:
                    j = json.dump(entity)
                    f.write(j)
                    f.write('\n')
                bulk_ = []

    if bulk_:
        with open(file_path, 'a') as f:
            for entity in bulk_:
                j = json.dump(entity)
                f.write(j)
                f.write('\n')
```